# Could debug logs slow down the application?

Tags: apex, debugging, performance

In my apex applications i have tons of the `System.debug('...')` outputs. Should i remove it all for the production use? What is the best practice for this?

Comment: Have you done any research before asking this question?

Comment: @DanielBlackhall I have not found any topic on the Internet, which has a relevance to Salesforce. I tried to remove my debugs and then start the application again, but noted no significant difference.

Comment: Is there any centralized place in salesforce to turn down all the debug logs for a particular file or environment ?

Comment: @PramodKumar You can override the `Log Filters` on the Apex Class Page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes debug statements are good to debug but eventually at back end salesforce would have written parser to parse and print it .So its one of the best practice to comment all system.debug when code is moved to production.

for a project my code was reviewed by sfdc technical architect and his suggestion was to comment all this debug statements before moving to production.So trusting salesforce Architect that he had strong reason to suggest me to do this .

Answer (score 4):

Best practice would be to remove them from Production. I don't think you would notice significant performance difference, but they count as script statements so if you have loads of them in there, particularly in loops etc., then you run the risk of hitting the limit on the number of script statements.

Comment: Thank you Doug! With Winter 14 release The code statement limit will be removed (but a new CPU time limit comes).

Comment: I would leave in sufficient debug statements so that if a) Production error occurs and b) your debug statements would speed the resolution of the issue over all other diagnostic approaches. That said, there are other diagnostic approaches including Developer Console, custom object diagnostic logs, and very robust internal error checking with superb error messages indicating the likely root cause

Answer (score 1):

Definitely debug logs slow downs the application performance. I am from java back ground. In my application, I used to log almost every request and response in the application. It was slowing down my application performance and when i stopped to log all those request, it improved my application performance drastically.